# Set background of a selected listview row

Tags: android, listview, background

I have a listview which is populated with locations, When you click on a location this brings up jobs to be done within this location. When all jobs have been completed you then click on a ok button now at this point I want the selected location row in the listview background colour to change. 
What I have so far for the button

```
 mOkBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            View listView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.area_list);  
            listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            mArea.checkResult = CheckResult.OK;
            mArea.checkTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L;
            showResults();
        }
    });
```

At the moment this changes the whole listview green, but im not sure how to get it to change just the selected row.

thx

Comment: Do you want to persist the color of selected item??

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color of listview as follows,

```
 ListView listview=new ListView(this);
 listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

If your listview shows black when you scrolling the listview then add the some code in xml as

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
 android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
```

I think it may helpful to you.

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/plainbg">


 <ListView 
 android:id="@+id/foodlistview"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
 android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
 android:divider="@android:color/white"
 android:dividerHeight="2px"
 ></ListView></RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting the colour, you need a selector. You can set this on your list using the android:listSelector attribute as :

```
 <ListView 
 android:id="@+id/foodlistview"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
 android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
 android:divider="@android:color/white"
 android:dividerHeight="2px"
 android:listSelector="list_selector"
 ></ListView>
```

And list_selector.xml  :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_disabled" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" />
  <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" />
</selector>
```