# Make ListView Item Selection remain Stable

Tags: android, listview

How to make ListView Item Selection remain stable ?

```
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"        
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"       
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        />
```

Comment: where is your adapter code?

Comment: Do as MD told you and make a selector like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19538463/2591002)

Comment: u need to handle else part in getView() like this : `if (selectedIndex != -1 && selectedIndex == position) {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yourColor);
    }else{  v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.defaultColor); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to make `getSelectedIndex()` and `setSelectedIndex()` method in your adapter.

```
private int selectedIndex;

public int getSelectedIndex() {
    return selectedIndex;
}

public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
    this.selectedIndex = index;

    // Re-draw the list by informing the view of the changes
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and then

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     .......

    // Highlight the selected item in the list
    if (selectedIndex != -1 && selectedIndex == position) {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yourColor);
    }

    return v;
}
```

and used from `onListItemClick(....)`

```
 adapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
```

### Another way as @Sun said

Used gradient to make list selection remain stable

**gradient_bg.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
  android:startColor="#7ecce8"
  android:centerColor="#7ecce8"
  android:endColor="#7ecce8"
  />
</shape>
```

**gradient_bg_hover.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
  android:startColor="#7ecce8"
  android:centerColor="#7ecce8"
  android:endColor="#7ecce8"
  />
</shape>
```

**list_selector.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
 </selector>
```

finally in `ListView`, use `listSelector` property like below:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
```

Comment: now selection remains stable but whenever i do tap on any other list item, its not refreshing list still getting old selected rows as well

Comment: @Sun add `adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);` in your Activity

Comment: @Sun Thnx. and your answer also useful to others that's why +1 up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69790/discussion-between-sun-and-m-d).

Answer (score 2):

I have used gradient to make list selection remain stable

gradient_bg.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#7ecce8"
      android:centerColor="#7ecce8"
      android:endColor="#7ecce8"
      />
</shape>
```

gradient_bg_hover.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#7ecce8"
      android:centerColor="#7ecce8"
      android:endColor="#7ecce8"
      />
</shape>
```

list_selector.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
     android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
     android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

finally in ListView, use listSelector property like below:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
```

Comment: @SweetWisherヅ i followed your link as well but that was not helping me in making selection stable, but yes that gave me an idea and that's why i ticked your answer as useful.. but as you know MD was the first who started helping me in this and i accepted his answer... anyways thank you so much

Comment: Lolz... I din't ask you to accept mine.. happy coding

Comment: @SweetWisherヅ great person .. good thoughts -- deserves salute :)

Answer (score 1):

> You need to keep track of selected item and accordingly change the background of the list row.

1.Change the selected item's position in item click :

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3) {
        adapter.setSelectedItem(position);
}
```

2.Get selected item and set background :

```
public class AudioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Audio> {
    Integer selected_position = -1;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Your Code

        if (position == selected_position) {
            // set selected color
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yourSelectedColor);
        } else {
            // set default color
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yourDefaultColor);
        }
    }

    public int getSelectedItem() {
        return selected_position;
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(int index) {
        this.selected_position = index;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps ツ